# Angular - ng-repeat with select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to fill an select / dropdown from an ng-repeat?

Like this:

```
<select ng-repeat='spalte in selectedItem.spalten' ng-model="item.id" ng-options="item.id for item in spalte"></select>
```

I need to create as many select fields as "spalten" available and to fill those selects will the values from "spalte" (coming from Laravel pivot table)

Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yeah that should work...

Comment: Should not be a problem

Comment: You should use `ng-options`

Comment: ng-repeat should be on option tag, not select and not together with ng-options.

Comment: Nono, I need multiple select fields and not use the repeat for the options.